# Почему pip в виртуальном окружении работает как внешний pip

Tags: python, pycharm, pip

Я создал виртуальное окружение в Pycharm и хотел установить pygame (`pip install pygame`) через терминал в Pycharm. Вывело:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pygame in c:\users\я\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (2.1.2)
```

Разумеется в виртуальном окружении его нет и при попытке запустить программу с pygame вылезает ошибка.
Вот ещё пример: пишу `pip freeze` он выводит библиотеки с внешнего питона, а не с внутреннего.
Как сделать так чтобы pip виртуальным стал?

Comment: А вы уверены, что виртуальное окружение было активировано?

Comment: В PyCharm оно автоматически запускается

Comment: Ну если он у вас работает как глобальный pip то всё же не факт(И да я знаю что он сам запускаеться, но везде существуют исключения). И всё же присутствует ли у вас надпись в терминале Pycharm-а "(venv) ". Есть ли в терминале какие-то ошибки?

Answer (score 0):

В настройках пайчарма найди Project: "Имя твоего проекта" -> Python Interpreter -> Добавь интерпретатор из своего виртуального окружения(файл python.exe в папке с окружением проекта). Тогда всё заработает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня python и так по адресу ...\my_project\venv\Scripts\python.exe  там стоит